# How does 'DNU RESTORE' determine if a dependency is a project reference rather than a package reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm getting my knickers in a twist with 'project' versus 'package' (ie Nuget package)  references in asp.net 5.0. I'd really like for someone to explain a bit more fully the way references are pulled in in asp.net 5.0. How does a 'dnu restore' determine if something is a project reference rather than a package reference?

I had thought that a reference would be pulled in as a project if the projects were in the same directory, but this is clearly not the whole story. It does appear that you can have a deeper directory nesting and still pick up the project reference.

Here is an outline of my common project structure:

I've got a set of projects, some of which reference one another. There are libraries called TextHelpers and MathHelpers and a project called MainProject. The libraries live in a folder called Libraries, and the MainProject lives in a folder called Tools. This separation is necessary as Libraries and Tools belong to different Git repos:

- Root/Libraries/TextHelpers.Project1 - version 1.0.0-*
- Root/Libraries/TextHelpers.Project2 - version 1.0.0-*
- Root/Libraries/MathHelpers.Project1 - version 1.0.0-*
- Root/Libraries/MathHelpers.Project2 - version 1.0.0-*
- Root/Tools/MainProject - version 1.0.0-*

Usually MainProject references the libraries as Nuget packages from a private Nuget repository (just a folder on the file system) which serves the libraries.

While I'm building MainProject, however, sometimes I need to make a change to one of the library projects, or sometimes I'd like to step into the files without using a Nuget symbol server. For this reason, I'd like to switch to referencing the (live) projects rather than from the (static) Nuget packages. How would I do this?

I've discovered this much so far: if I have a global.json file, a 'dnu restore' creates a project.lock.json with 'project' rather than 'package' references. Is this the whole story?

Comment: Could you include `global.json` or optionally `nuget.config`, which you use in your solution? In you have no `nuget.config` in your solution then you can include the content of `%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config`. What displays `dnu feeds list`? Do you use `dnu restore` explicitly in command line without any parameters (like `--no-cache`, which is interesting, see `dnu restore --help`) or you use just Visual Studio 2015 for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dnu` and `dnx` look in the following folders:

1. The folder where the current project is (that means the parent folder of the folder containing the `project.json` of the current project). E.g. if you have `repo/src/project1/project.json` it will look in `repo/src`
2. Any other folder included in `global.json`

Then the algorithm is really naive: if it finds a folder with the name matching the package in any the folders mentioned above it will assume those are the sources for that package.

For example, if you have

```
src/P1/project.json
src/System.Collections/project.json
```

and in `src/P1/project.json` you have a reference to `System.Collections`, it will use `src/System.Collection` instead of the NuGet package `System.Collections`. Projects take precedence over packages.

Caveats:

1. Since the algoritm looks in the current folder and everything in `global.json` you might be able to reference some projects from one folder but not another. If in my previous example you'd add a `test/T1/project.json` project but `src` is not in `global.json` then the projects in `src` will reference `System.Collections` the project while `T1` will reference the package (installed in the global packages folder).
2. There's no verification to see if the project reference is actually that package. If the name matches, it's a match. So an empty project could replace any package.
3. If you have multiple project with the same name you can get in trouble.

Hope this helps and answers your question.

Side note: with `dotnet` (the tool replacing `dnx`) you can specify for every reference if you want the project or the package to have higher priority.

Comment: Excellent answer Victor. Thanks. So the secret to turning on/off the inclusion of external projects versus packages in my setup is the "projects" property in the global.json file? I'm presuming that the system looks for the first 'global.json' file in the folder hierarchy above the project.json file that is being restored.

Comment: Exactly, it uses the nearest `global.json` in the parent folders.